# OpenCV windows always minimized on Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, minimized

i have a problem with OpenCV in Python2 on Linux. Whenever i open up a window, it starts minimized. Is there any easy way to force the window to start on top?

my code:
    import cv2

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, pic = video.read()
cv2.imwrite("/home/karlosss/img.png", pic)

img = cv2.imread('/home/karlosss/img.png', 0) 
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imshow("window", img2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious to find out who else has got this!

Comment: Solved - all i had to do was to move the cv2 window into a tkinter one